# Prove that in an arithmetic progression of 3 prime numbers the common difference is divisible by 6

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Here's the question from the book:

> Three prime numbers $p, q$, and $r$, all greater than 3, form an arithmetic progression:
>   $$\begin{align} p&=p \\ q&=p+d \\r&=p+2d \end{align}$$
>   Prove that $d$ is divisible by 6.

Now here's what I have done:

For $d$ to be divisible by 6 it has to be divisible by 2 and 3. Now for proving divisibility by 2; $d$ has to be even, or else one of $p, q, r$ will be even. Hence it is divisible by 2.

Can anyone help me find how to prove that $d$ is divisible by 3?

Comment: 5,7,11 is not an arithmetic sequence.

Comment: messed it up.edited the question

Comment: Here is another hint: Suppose $d$ is not divisible by 3. This means that $d = 3k+1$ or $d = 3k+2$ for some $k$. You also know that $p$ is not divisible by 3 since $p > 3$. This means that $p = 3s+1$ or $p = 3s+2$. Now combine all these cases and show that in each possible combination either $q$ or $r$ must be divisible by 3.

Comment: @Ananthakrishna Your logic for $d$ being even is very muddled.  It's certainly not true that if $d$ is odd then $p,q,r$ must be even.  Only that at least one of them would be even.  Perhaps if you write out that argument carefully you'll see how the $3\mid d$ case can be made to work similarly.

Comment: @ErickWong Yes,it is true that one of p,q and r will be even;I think i need to plan out before asking a question on how my question should look like.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HINT:

$$p(p+d)(p+2d)=p(p^2+3pd+2d^2)$$

Now as $3$ is prime, if $3\nmid d;(d,3)=1$

$\implies d\equiv\pm1\pmod3\implies d^2\equiv1$

If $3\nmid p,p^2\equiv1$ as well (we don't need $p$ to be prime!)

Then $(p+d)(p+2d)=p^2+3pd+2d^2\equiv1+0+2\cdot1\equiv0\pmod3\iff3|(p+d)(p+2d)$

$\implies3$ must divide at least one of $p+d,p+2d$ each of which $>3$

Comment: That's a valid proof of course. I doubt that it will help this student understand the problem or improve his./her technique. :(

Comment: I think i got it

Comment: can you explain it in a bit more detail.i couldn't get it.

Comment: @Ananthakrishna, Please pinpoint your confusion

Comment: the last 2 steps

Comment: @Ananthakrishna, We have $p^2,d^2\equiv1\pmod3\implies P^2+3pd+2d^2\equiv1+0+2\equiv0\pmod3$

Comment: figured that out a bit late;Got it

Answer (score 3):

**Hint** $\ $ Primes $> 3$ have the form $\,6k\pm1.\,$ If  $\,p\not\equiv q\pmod 6\,$ then there are $2$ possibilities

$${\rm mod}\ 6\!:\quad \begin{array}{rrr}p & q & r\\ -1 & 1 & 3\\ 1 & -1 & -3\end{array}\ \ \qquad\quad $$

thus $\,3\mid r,\,$ contra $\,3 < r\,$ is prime. Therefore $\ p\equiv q\pmod 6,\, $ so $\ 6\mid q-p = d$

**Remark** $\ $ Note that the proof does not require that $\,p,q,r\,$ are primes $> 3.\,$ Rather, it requires only the weaker hypothesis that they are all  $\equiv \pm1 \pmod 6,\,$ i.e. all coprime to $\,6.$

Answer (score 2):

This is the special case $k=3$, of the following fact.

> Let $p,p+d, \dots, p+(k-1)d$ be an arithmetic progression of length $k$ of primes with $p>k$, then $q\mid d$ for each prime $q \le k$ (that is $\prod_{q \le k}q \mid d$).

To see this just note that if $d \not\equiv 0 \mod q$ then $0,d, \dots, (k-1)d$ is a complete set of residues modulo $q$. Thus for some $j$ we have $j d \equiv -p \mod q$, whence $q \mid p +jd$, a contradiction to $p+jd $ being prime (note $p+jd > q$).

Comment: Interesting Fact;Can you tell me how you got $jd \cong -p\ mod\  q$.I dont know much of this congruency thing.

Comment: Since $d$ is not $0$ modulo $q$, the numbers $0, d, 2d, \dots , (q-1)d$ will represent *all* classes modulo $q$. To see this just note that they are all different modulo $q$ as $q \nmid d (i-j)$ as $|i - j| < q$. Since these are all classes there must be one that corresponds to the class of $-p$.